# Can I use and access the Chrome storage API within a chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension which just contains a content script, I'd like to take and store some user input (like settings) for use during the process.

Am I going about this the right way, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use an [Options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) and store settings in [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), as this is directly accessible from both extension pages and content scripts. You could even use sync storage to persist settings across multiple browsers of the same user.

Options page will be exposed through the extensions list, right-click on the extension icon, and you can use your own logic to call [`chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-openOptionsPage) (though you can't do it from a content script — don't be afraid to use an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)).

While you could inject some UI into the page itself with a content script, that's a lot more work as to not break the host page.